# How to update a related node in a FOREACH loop?

Tags: neo4j

I'm adding a bunch of nodes to my graph using FOREACH.

However, sometimes these nodes will refer to nodes that already exist (with an existing index), so in that case, I just add some properties to the node.

However, if the node does exist, **I also want to update a node that it is related to**.

Here's a diagram:

[image]

I have written a Cypher query that works:

```
FOREACH (item in [$list] |
    MERGE (check :label {index: item.index})

    MERGE (check)-[:r]->(related)
    ON CREATE SET
        check.value= item.value,
        check.property= item.stuff
    ON MATCH SET
        check.value= item.value,
        check.proprety= item.stuff,
        related.value = related.value + node.value     
)
```

However, it always creates an empty `(check)-[:r]->(related)` relationship on the `(check)` node. So the result of this query is this:

[image]

In summary, when `MERGE`ing nodes in a `FOREACH` loop, how can I update related nodes that nodes in the loop may be connected to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an optional match instead of the second merge :

```
UNWIND $list AS item
MERGE (check :label {index: item.index})
ON CREATE SET
   check.value= item.value,
   check.property= item.stuff
ON MATCH SET
   check.value= item.value,
   check.property= item.stuff 

OPTIONAL MATCH (:label {index: item.index})-[:r]->(related)
SET related.value = related.value + item.value
```

Hope this helps,
Tom

Comment: Thanks Tom. This would be exactly what I'm looking for, but unfortunately I cannot use `MATCH` inside a `FOREACH` loop.

Comment: Excellent point, forgive me. Would UNWIND do the trick (https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/unwind/) ? The final example on that page looks a quite like what you want ... I adapted the answer to reflect that but haven't actually tried it yet.

Comment: Thanks, I think `UNWIND` is what I might be looking for. My example is a much simplified version of my query, so I'll see if I can get something working. Thanks again.